# How to update document meta data using powershell

Tags: 2013, powershell

I'm iterating through all files of a document library using powershell trying to update some files in some folders. I can read the file properties but I'm not able to update them.

Here is my code:

```
foreach($list in $web.Lists) {

    if ($list.Title -ne "My Documents") {
        continue
    }

    Write-Host $list.Title

    foreach($folder in $list.RootFolder.SubFolders) {

        if ($folder.Name -ne "My Folder") {
            continue
        }

        Write-Host $folder.Name -ForegroundColor Gray

        foreach($file in $folder.Files) {

            # field type: users and groups
            Write-Host $file.Properties['My Cust Prop 1']
            # output: 40

            # field type: date and time
            Write-Host $file.Properties['My Cust Prop 2']
            # output: 2012-07-11T00:00:00Z

            #This does not work:
            #$file.CheckOut();
            #$file.Properties['My Cust Prop 1'] = 30
            #$file.Properties['My Cust Prop 2'] = '2012-10-25T00:00:00Z'
            #$file.CheckIn('Test');

        }

    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I have to change the code to make this work?

How can I get the User ID if I only have the AD account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work, you need to call Update method before Checking In

```
$file.CheckOut();
$file.Properties['My Cust Prop 1'] = 30
$file.Properties['My Cust Prop 2'] = '2012-10-25T00:00:00Z'
$file.Update();
$file.CheckIn('Test');
```

Or you can try

```
$listItem = $web.GetListItem($file.ServerRelativeUrl);
$listItem.File.Checkout();
$listItem.Properties['My Cust Prop 1'] = 30
$listItem.Properties['My Cust Prop 2'] = '2012-10-25T00:00:00Z'
$listItem.Update();
$listItem.File.Checkin('Updated')
```